# IIS Url Rewrite rule not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect all traffic from:

https://funfinda.com &
http://funfinda.com &
http://www.funfinda.com &

to https://www.funfinda.com

I've tried adding this URL rewrite rule, I've also tried using "redirect" instead of "rewrite" but its not working...

```
<rule name="Funfinda redirects" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^funfinda.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.funfinda.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: What *is* happening instead?

Comment: Basically the (SSL) funfinda.com & https://funfinda.com both go through to the actual website. Which causes a 500..